# Error after every start of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I don't know what happened to my Ubuntu Desktop 15.04. When I start Ubuntu, I am getting this error every time. When I try to update ubuntu, it does not get updated. Please help me to resolve this issue.. I love Ubuntu very much but i am not an expert..

I tried the online solution from the Google, but nothing has worked out for me. I tried to find the solution over stackoverflow but this error could not be found.
Please help me to solve the issue.

I don't want to ignore this error.

Thanks

Error screen shot - [here](http://s11.postimg.org/61hfkpflf/Screenshot_from_2016_03_11_07_29_58.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't appear to be related to updating your system.

Once you have booted, click on the Continue button for your error message which should make the message disappear (you may be asked to enter your password to submit the error message if you keep the option 'Send an error report' enabled.

Open a terminal through ONE of the following methods (taken from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

- Dash -> Search for Terminal
- Dash -> More Apps -> 'See More Results' -> Terminal
- Dash -> More Apps -> Accessories -> Terminal
- Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>   + <kbd>T</kbd>

Then type: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Enter your password when prompted.